# How do I access my external MYSQL database from Asterisk dialplan?

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to access my external database from an Asterisk dialplan but I get the error "No application MySQL for extension mycontextname".

So I run the command “module show like mysql” and it shows 0 module. I read on a blog that I have to add mysql addons such as app_addon_sql_mysql.so module, but the once I found isn't solving the situation either. I still get 0 module after the "module show like mysql" command.

I am using Asterisk 13.10.0 and please which mysql module will work well for my Asterisk version, also where can I get it?

Comment: Asterisk 13 has app_mysql.so module. Try: module load app_mysql.so

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is outdated AND addtional application. You should not use it. If you HAVE, you need compile it(do make menuconfig before make).

Recommended way is use of func_odbc or REALTIME

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I don't like doing database stuff in the Asterisk dialplan. I find it ugly, difficult to write (quoting), difficult to maintain, and fragile.

I prefer to write applications (logic and database access) in an AGI. You have 'full' access to the database and you 'hide' all the details in a nice black box where your code can be checked by a real compiler (or script interpreter).

Comment: AGI run NEW process every time you use it. Sure you can write as you wish, but perfomance of func_odbc will be much better in most cases.

Comment: Yes, process creation is more 'expensive' but the cost is very small unless you write your AGIs in a scripting language and you execute dozens between interactions with the caller.

Comment: Sorry. Got caught by the '5 minute edit' timer...

Yes, process creation is more 'expensive' but the cost is very small unless you write your AGIs in a scripting language and you execute dozens between interactions with the caller or are processing hundreds of simultaneous calls.

I write most of my AGIs in C so I can execute xxx in the time it takes an AGI written in Perl or PHP to load the interpreter, parse the source, generate the byte code, and then execute.

Comment: But that will be not faster then func_odbc and seams like will take more time(development time) in most cases for anyone who know sql at advanced or expert level.

Comment: I agree that a single query will be (nanoseconds?) faster via the dialplan than by an AGI. As your 'application' grows, the differential shrinks.

This does not change my opinion that "I find it ugly, difficult to write (quoting), difficult to maintain, and fragile."

Comment: i find C application harder maintain then dialplan, really. Difference will be near 20-50ms. Anyway, it is unlikly people will use C for agi, more likly they will use php. Thats why i say your answer is not so nice for MOST people. I know no other person who do agi in C, really.